# Center a window via command line

Tags: command-line, window

Is there a way to either place a window in the center of the screen after it is opened, or cause it to open in the center of the screen?

This needs to be done using command line.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The **[wmctrl](http://tomas.styblo.name/wmctrl/)** tool provides command line access to almost all features defined in the [EWMH (Extended Window Manager Hints)](http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-1.3.html) specification. **It can be used**, for example, to get information about the window manager, to get a detailed list of desktops and managed windows, to **switch** and **resize** desktops, to make windows **full-screen**, **always-above** or **sticky**, and to **activate**, **close**, **move**, **resize**, **maximize** and **minimize** them.

You can install it by:

```
sudo apt-get install wmctrl
```

You can get information about your virtual desktops (workspaces) with `wmctrl -d`:

```
$ wmctrl -d
0  * DG: 2720x1536  VP: 0,0  WA: 0,24 1360x744  N/A
```

And list open windows with `wmctrl -l`.

```
$ wmctrl -l
0x02000004  0 onezero Desktop
0x02e00002  0     N/A DNDCollectionWindow
0x02e00003  0     N/A launcher
0x01e00004  0 onezero cairo-dock
0x02e00004  0     N/A panel
0x04800061  0 onezero Transmission
0x02e0000a  0     N/A Dash
0x03a00044  0 onezero arranging windows from the gnu/linux command line with wmctrl ~ Moving to Freedom - Chromium
0x04400006  0 onezero one@onezero: ~
0x04c000e9  0 onezero Google - Mozilla Firefox
```

The `-G` option shows you the geometry of the windows:

```
$ wmctrl -lG
0x02000004  0 0    0    1360 768  onezero Desktop
0x02e00002  0 -1460 -868 1360 768      N/A DNDCollectionWindow
0x02e00003  0 0    24   58   744      N/A launcher
0x01e00004  0 290  653  780  115  onezero cairo-dock
0x02e00004  0 0    0    1360 24       N/A panel
0x04800061  0 408  95   732  500  onezero Transmission
0x02e0000a  0 -1402 -844 1302 744      N/A Dash
0x03a00044  0 0    24   1360 744  onezero Center a window via command line - Ask Ubuntu - Stack Exchange - Chromium
0x04400006  0 127  94   983  434  onezero one@onezero: ~
0x04c000e9  0 5    47   1349 715  onezero Google - Mozilla Firefox
```

You can specify a window by referencing its title or partial title after `-r`. `-e` is for moving and resizing.

```
wmctrl -r "Mozilla Firefox" -e <G>,<X>,<Y>,<W>,<H>
```

where:

```
<G>: Gravity specified as a number. The numbers are defined in the EWMH specification. The value of zero is particularly
     useful, it means "use the default gravity of the window".
<X>,<Y>: Coordinates of new position of the window.
<W>,<H>: New width and height of the window.
```

So, to move a window to the upper left corner and make it 1000 pixels wide by 700 tall, you’d use `0,0,0,1000,700`:

```
wmctrl -r "Mozilla Firefox" -e 0,0,0,1000,700
```

[image: window at the upper left corner]

To move/resize it, I used the workaround of “unmaximizing” it first, using the `-b` option

```
wmctrl -r "Mozilla Firefox" -b remove,maximized_vert,maximized_horz
wmctrl -r "Mozilla Firefox" -b add,maximized_vert,maximized_horz
```

[image]

#### The things you need to understand first

- The `-e` option expects a list of comma separated integers: `gravity,X,Y,width,height`

  [image: my screen resolution]

  Above is my screen resolution, so `width` = 1360 and `height` = 786.
- Aligning a window to left-half of the screen:

  ```
  wmctrl -r "Mozilla Firefox" -e 1,0,0,680,768
  ```
- Aligning a window to right-half of the screen:

  ```
  wmctrl -r "Mozilla Firefox" -e 1,680,0,680,768
  ```
- Aligning a window to the **center of the screen** (1360 / 4 = 340):

  ```
  wmctrl -r "Mozilla Firefox" -e 1,340,0,680,768
  ```

  [image: window aligned at the center of the screen]

Manipulate the above commands as needed for your screen settings.

For more help:

- [Aero Snap feature for GNU/Linux with wmctrl](https://web.archive.org/web/20111112133826/http://www.returnfalse.net/log/aero-snap-feature-for-gnulinux-with-wmctrl/)
- [arranging windows from the gnu/linux command line with wmctrl](http://movingtofreedom.org/2010/08/10/arranging-windows-from-the-gnulinux-command-line-with-wmctrl/)
- [Extended Window Manager Hints](http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-1.3.html#id2507241)
- [wmctrl user documentation (examples)](http://spiralofhope.com/wmctrl-examples.html)

Answer (score 12):

that works with the currently active window

```
IFS='x' read screenWidth screenHeight < <(xdpyinfo | grep dimensions | grep -o '[0-9x]*' | head -n1)

width=$(xdotool getactivewindow getwindowgeometry --shell | head -4 | tail -1 | sed 's/[^0-9]*//')
height=$(xdotool getactivewindow getwindowgeometry --shell | head -5 | tail -1 | sed 's/[^0-9]*//')

newPosX=$((screenWidth/2-width/2))
newPosY=$((screenHeight/2-height/2))

xdotool getactivewindow windowmove "$newPosX" "$newPosY"
```

Comment: This needs `bash` or `zsh` to run, plain `sh` won't work.

Comment: Works , except under Unity for windows that are 1/2 or 1/4 screen tiled (e.g. drag a window to the right side, it will occupy the right half of your screen). These windows seems to be special, and I don't know which `xdotool` action to call to first make them "normal" windows before calling `windowmove`. Ideas?

Comment: Found a solution to my problem on [this askubuntu thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/682027/arrange-windows-by-script/682688). Involves calling `wmctrl` too, better solutions welcome. TL;DR: call `wmctrl -ir "$(xdotool getactivewindow)" -b remove,maximized_vert,maximized_horz` before the final `xdotool getactivewindow windowmove` call.

Comment: This apparently moves the window to the center of the visible screen space -- so if you're working on two monitors, it will position the window right in the middle split up between the two screens. Is there a way to center the window within one screen (e.g. the primary one) only?

Answer (score 4):

If anyone wants a code snippet to copy/paste to do this, here's one:

```
winname='foo'
IFS='x' read sw sh < <(xdpyinfo | grep dimensions | grep -o '[0-9x]*' | head -n1)
read wx wy ww wh < <(wmctrl -lG | grep $winname | sed 's/^[^ ]* *[^ ]* //;s/[^0-9 ].*//;')
wmctrl -r $winname -e 0,$(($sw/2-$ww/2)),$(($sh/2-$wh/2)),$ww,$wh
```

Replace `foo` with the name of the window you want to center in the first line, of course.

---

**Explanation** (breakdown in the form of an example console session):

*Getting the screen dimensions*

```
llama@llama:~$ xdpyinfo | grep dimensions
  dimensions:    1920x1080 pixels (508x285 millimeters)
llama@llama:~$ xdpyinfo | grep dimensions | grep -o '[0-9x]*'
1920x1080
x
508x285
llama@llama:~$ xdpyinfo | grep dimensions | grep -o '[0-9x]*' | head -n1
1920x1080
llama@llama:~$ IFS='x' read sw sh < <(xdpyinfo | grep dimensions | grep -o '[0-9x]*' | head -n1)
llama@llama:~$ echo $sw $sh
1920 1080
```

*Getting the window's geometry information*

```
llama@llama:~$ wmctrl -lG | grep foo
0x00a0000c  0 1113 510  722  475  llama foo
llama@llama:~$ wmctrl -lG | grep foo | sed 's/^[^ ]*//;'
  0 1113 510  722  475  llama foo
llama@llama:~$ wmctrl -lG | grep foo | sed 's/^[^ ]* *[^ ]*//;'
 1113 510  722  475  llama foo
llama@llama:~$ wmctrl -lG | grep foo | sed 's/^[^ ]* *[^ ]* //;s/[^0-9 ].*//;'
1143 505  722  475  
llama@llama:~$ read wx wy ww wh < <(wmctrl -lG | grep foo | sed 's/^[^ ]* *[^ ]* //;s/[^0-9 ].*//;')
llama@llama:~$ echo $wx $wy $ww $wh
1143 505 722 475
```

*Moving the window*

```
llama@llama:~$ echo 0,foo,bar,$ww,$wh
0,foo,bar,722,475
llama@llama:~$ echo 0,$(($sw/2)),bar,$ww,$wh                                    
0,960,bar,722,475
llama@llama:~$ echo 0,$(($sw/2-$ww/2)),bar,$ww,$wh
0,599,bar,722,475
llama@llama:~$ echo 0,$(($sw/2-$ww/2)),$(($sh/2-$wh/2)),$ww,$wh
0,599,303,722,475
```

Answer (score -1):

Most applications should honor the --geometry parameter when starting up (some prefer -geometry, try the second if the first doesn't work for you):

```
gnome-terminal --geometry 80x25+100+100
```

The geometry parameter has this form:

```
WIDTHxHEIGHT+XOFF+YOFF
```

You can leave unneeded parts out:

```
gnome-terminal --geometry +20+50 #No size, just offsets
```

For more details:

```
man X
```

then press "/" and search for GEOMETRY SPECIFICATIONS

or see here: http://www.cotse.com/dlf/man/xwindows/geometry.htm